# Can you make a google chrome extension that remembers the user?

Tags: google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension

A friend and I want to do a personal project in which a user inputs all their classes and class details onto a website/extension and then we are going to build it into a main hub that people can use when in school. Could we use a google chrome extension for this? The user should be able to sign in on various computers and always access their hub. We are doing this to avoid having a username password database as we do not feel ready to be playing with that.

Answer (score 0):

I recently created an extension with similar features. However, I integrated a database of logins which really wasn't too difficult to do. I would be more than happy to work on the project with you. However, I believe you need to clarify when you say that you want `to avoid having a username password database`, but you want users to be able to access their "hub". How can you maintain consistent user data without a database? Without some sort of server/database for retaining this information, it is virtually impossible to accomplish your goal with a Google Chrome extension. Please clarify your question, especially the goal of the project, how you plan on storing data, and what a "hub" is.

Assuming one of my possible interpretations for what I think you are trying to say is correct, however, I will suggest certain methods:

- Trying to keep logins on individual computers? You can `localStorage` & `cookies` to maintain logins on local machines.
- Remembering user data without an online "database"? You can do this by setting up a machine as a server, or if you have critical mass, a cheap although inefficient way would be to have data constantly bounced around through P2P messages or sockets (please don't though).
- Remembering user data with an online database? Simply use a [mySQL table](http://youtu.be/QicZiDBDP14)!

Comment: That's very helpful, what I meant when I said I didn't want to use a database was using cookies or local storage. However, maybe what I did need was some clarification and you gave it to me. I have a computer with a half broken screen. Could that be used as a database? How hard is it to setup? One thing I was also worried about is having the website hacked and people losing their passwords usernames. At the moment I do not know any protective and security programming at all for inputs such as those.